# MongoDB (Atlas) connection using Node.js without using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have done MongoDB (Atlas) connection using Node.js without using mongoose , but it's not working and giving the following error.

> MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld
> at parseSrvConnectionString (E:\nodejsUdemy\express\shop_mongoDb_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:41:21)
> at parseConnectionString (E:\nodejsUdemy\express\shop_mongoDb_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:556:12)
> at connect (E:\nodejsUdemy\express\shop_mongoDb_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:277:3)
> at E:\nodejsUdemy\express\shop_mongoDb_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:222:5                                                                                at maybePromise (E:\nodejsUdemy\express\shop_mongoDb_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:719:3)
> at MongoClient.connect (E:\nodejsUdemy\express\shop_mongoDb_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:218:10)
> at Function.MongoClient.connect (E:\nodejsUdemy\express\shop_mongoDb_v1\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:440:22)
> at mongoConnect (E:\nodejsUdemy\express\shop_mongoDb_v1\util\database.js:5:17)
> at Object. (E:\nodejsUdemy\express\shop_mongoDb_v1\app.js:34:1)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)

**My database connection code is following**

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const mongoConnect = callback=>{
 MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://saptarshi:FollowYou@cluster0-molcn.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
.then(client=>{
 console.log('connected');
callback(client);
})
.catch(err=>{
console.log(err);
console.log('check');
});
};
module.exports = mongoConnect;
```

and my main file connection code is following

```
mongoConnect(client=>{console.log(client);app.listen(3000);});
```

Comment: Driver version?

Comment: See  http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/tutorials/connect/ for proper usage.

Comment: Driver version = 3.6

Comment: almost tried everything , but can't connect to database

Comment: I can't seem to find anything wrong with the code you posted. I tried it out with a different database URL(connection string) and it worked fine. Maybe you want to double-check your database URL.